# Cross-validation on XGBClassifier for multiclass classification in python

Tags: python, classification, cross-validation, xgboost

I'm trying to perform cross-validation on a XGBClassifier for a multi-class classification problem using the following code adapted from http://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/03/complete-guide-parameter-tuning-xgboost-with-codes-python/

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xgboost as xgb
from xgboost.sklearn import  XGBClassifier
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn import cross_validation, metrics
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV


def modelFit(alg, X, y, useTrainCV=True, cvFolds=5, early_stopping_rounds=50):
    if useTrainCV:
        xgbParams = alg.get_xgb_params()
        xgTrain = xgb.DMatrix(X, label=y)
        cvresult = xgb.cv(xgbParams,
                      xgTrain,
                      num_boost_round=alg.get_params()['n_estimators'],
                      nfold=cvFolds,
                      stratified=True,
                      metrics={'mlogloss'},
                      early_stopping_rounds=early_stopping_rounds,
                      seed=0,
                      callbacks=[xgb.callback.print_evaluation(show_stdv=False),                                                               xgb.callback.early_stop(3)])

        print cvresult
        alg.set_params(n_estimators=cvresult.shape[0])

    # Fit the algorithm
    alg.fit(X, y, eval_metric='mlogloss')

    # Predict
    dtrainPredictions = alg.predict(X)
    dtrainPredProb = alg.predict_proba(X)

    # Print model report:
    print "\nModel Report"
    print "Classification report: \n"
    print(classification_report(y_val, y_val_pred))
    print "Accuracy : %.4g" % metrics.accuracy_score(y, dtrainPredictions)
    print "Log Loss Score (Train): %f" % metrics.log_loss(y, dtrainPredProb)
    feat_imp = pd.Series(alg.booster().get_fscore()).sort_values(ascending=False)
    feat_imp.plot(kind='bar', title='Feature Importances')
    plt.ylabel('Feature Importance Score')


# 1) Read training set
print('>> Read training set')
train = pd.read_csv(trainFile)

# 2) Extract target attribute and convert to numeric
print('>> Preprocessing')
y_train = train['OutcomeType'].values
le_y = LabelEncoder()
y_train = le_y.fit_transform(y_train)
train.drop('OutcomeType', axis=1, inplace=True)

# 4) Extract features and target from training set
X_train = train.values

# 5) First classifier
xgb = XGBClassifier(learning_rate =0.1,
                    n_estimators=1000,
                    max_depth=5,
                    min_child_weight=1,
                    gamma=0,
                    subsample=0.8,
                    colsample_bytree=0.8,
                    scale_pos_weight=1,
                    objective='multi:softprob',
                    seed=27)

modelFit(xgb, X_train, y_train)
```

where `y_train` contains labels from 0 to 4. However, when I run this code I get the following error from the `xgb.cv` function `xgboost.core.XGBoostError: value 0for Parameter num_class should be greater equal to 1`. On the XGBoost doc I read that in the multiclass case xgb extrapolates the number of classes from the labels in the target vector, so I don't understand what is going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add the parameter ‘num_class’ to the xgb_param dictionary. This is also mentioned in the parameters description and in a comment from the link you provided above.

Comment: This solved my problem. I previously tried to set `num_class` in the XGBClassifier initialization but it didn't recognize the argument. Many thanks!

Comment: I don't follow, when I add that to the param grid I get  `ValueError: Invalid parameter num_class for estimator XGBClassifier. Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys().`

Comment: @sapo_cosmico this error doesn't come from XGBoost but from Sklearn and in the Sklearn XGB API you do not need to specify the num_class parameter explicitly. Anyway this is not the appropriate post for your comment: ask a separate question and delete the above comment from here.

Comment: I think this answer doesn't adequately face the issue, how is someone supposed to set the parameter is not explained. The error related to the sklearn wrapper but a lot of people have that issue and the solution is not apparent.

Comment: @LetsPlayYahtzee `how is someone supposed to set the parameter is not explained` This way: `xgb_param[‘num_class’] = k #k = number of classes` and that's the answer to the original question. `The error related to the sklearn` **Not** the error in the **OP question**, but the error in **another one's comment**.

Comment: This is totally wrong answer! API (http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest//python/python_api.html#module-xgboost.sklearn) is saying {num_class} is not part of the parameters! How he set it up?

Comment: @MTT yes, I am confused too.

Comment: @user6996876 So, just to make things clear you need to change `xgb_param = alg.get_xgb_params()` (thrid line inside the function) to `xgb_param[‘num_class’] = k`. Would you be able to check this please. 

Thanks 

Michael